# Best way to get value from html in python?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

So i want to scrape attribute value in python and currently i'm using regex but its not that effective so i wanted to know what should i use instead since many says that regex is bad for such thing.

Thanks

This is what i try to get.

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="99948555">
```

value always contains random numbers.

Comment: I would check out HTMLParser (https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use **BeautifulSoup** for this kind of parsing :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '<input type="hidden" name="test" value="99948555">'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('input')['name'], ':', soup.find('input')['value'])
# outputs : "test : 99948555"
```

What you are looking for here is : `soup.find('input')['value']`

See the documentation for usage and examples :
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

You can install it like this :

```
[python_binary] -m pip install bs4
```

Comment: `pip install beautifulsoup4`, actually

Comment: @cricket_007 depends on the version of python you are using.
On centOS for instance I have both python2.7 and python3.4, and using pip as a module works everytime, while pip binary only works for one version of python. So yes, I recommend using pip as a module.

Comment: Well i read documentation and got it working but i still can't retrieve only the value :/  i was thinking about turning result into string and regex numbers

Comment: Here's the code: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
      hidden_tags = soup.findAll("input", {'name': "test"})
      print(hidden_tags)

Comment: I've edited my answer : just use `soup.find('input')['value']`
When using `findAll()` you'll get a list, not a single object.

Comment: Thanks mate edited and it works just fine :)